# XAML Custom GridViewColumn Data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create an application that shows a list of 'Characters' with the properties Sleep, Hunger, Boredom and Health. I want to show the current characters and their status (status depends on which of the values is the biggest (Sleep, Hunger and Boredom)). Since status isnt a property in the character class I am not able to do it as I did with the name and health:

```
 <ListView x:Name="TamagochiList" Margin="10,34,10,118" ItemsSource="{Binding TamagochiList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Health" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Health}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I tried adding this in the viewmodel but I currently have no idea how to use it:

```
   public string TamagochiStatus(Tamagochi t)
        {
            if(t.Boredom >= t.Hunger && t.Boredom >= t.Sleep)
            {
                return "Bored";
            }
            if(t.Hunger >= t.Boredom && t.Hunger >= t.Sleep)
            {
                return "Hungry";
            }
            if(t.Sleep >= t.Boredom && t.Sleep >= t.Hunger)
            {
                return "Sleepy";
            }
            return "Geen status";
        }
```

Tried my best to find it but I was not sure about which keywords to choose.

Comment: I've answered based on the assumption that you are able to modify your `Character` class. Perhaps edit your question to clarify this if it is not the case.

Comment: Unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Status` is a property of the data itself, and not just an artifact for the UI, move the calculation into a property in your model class.

```
public class Character
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Health {get; set;}
     public int Boredom {get; set;}
     public int Sleep {get; set;}
     public int Hunger {get; set;}
     public string Status
     {
          get
          {
               if(Boredom >= Hunger && Boredom >= Sleep)
               {
                    return "Bored";
               }
               if(Hunger >= Boredom && t.Hunger >= Sleep)
               {
                    return "Hungry";
               }
               if(Sleep >= Boredom && Sleep >= Hunger)
               {
                    return "Sleepy";
               }
               return "Geen status";
          }
}
```

Then bind directly to that property via

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" />
```